# Python `read -n1 var`?

Tags: read, input-method, python3, user-input

Is there a Python 3 module that allows to input a single character, without having to press `Enter` afterwards?

Like Bash's `read -n1 var`?

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/payne92/11090057

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named `getch`, but it is not intsalled by default. To install it, use `pip3 install getch --user`.

you can use it this way :

```
import getch
c = getch.getche()
```